# Why does a fixed position table move the first 1px of a border when scrolling?

Tags: html, css

In this JSfiddle you can see the effect.
When you scroll down, the border at the top moves 1 px. and I can't figure out how to stop this. If you scroll to the right, the left border does the same.
I'd like the border to always remain visible.
I've tried adding "box-sizing: border-box;" to no avail. I simply can't prevent this behavior.

https://jsfiddle.net/jqn7m0ta/

Code (from above JSfiddle):

```html
<div style="height:500px; margin-top:2rem; margin-bottom:2rem; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;">
  <table style="border:1px solid #e8e8e8; font-size:1rem; margin:0; padding:0; table-layout:fixed; width:100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          a
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          b
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          c
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          d
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          e
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          f
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          g
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#e8e8e8; height:1000px">1</td>
        <td style="height:1000px">2</td>
        <td style="background-color:#e8e8e8; height:1000px">3</td>
        <td style="height:1000px">4</td>
        <td style="background-color:#e8e8e8; height:1000px">5</td>
        <td style="height:1000px">6</td>
        <td style="background-color:#e8e8e8; height:1000px">7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `table { border-collapse: collapse }` and voila. Also might move that border on table to the container div while you're at it and all those repetitive inline styles are a no-no.

Comment: because it's not the table that's sticky, It's the `<th>` it actually goes all the way up not just `1px`

Comment: Chris, I tried this -- border-collapse -- but you can see it doesn't fix the table. :(

Comment: Stephen, of course, I'm working on a WordPress plugin using a table and I don't want to inject a stylesheet for something I'm working on.

Comment: Updated JSfiddle w/border-collapse: https://jsfiddle.net/m76fxz4n/

Comment: On latest version of Chrome it doesn't work

Comment: initial: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0s728cxo9nb6ld/initial.png?dl=0

Comment: on scroll: https://www.dropbox.com/s/srhkb55vr1irsix/on-scroll.png?dl=0
notice the top most pixel ... from grey to white ... look very closely and you'll see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you want apply the border in Table, You can do one thing You apply the border to the parent element of table as in your case it is DIV element.

HTML Table element have default border-spacing:2px so you also need to modify it to the 0px.

Here is the code for your reference

```
<div style="border:1px solid #e8e8e8; height:500px; margin-top:2rem; margin-bottom:2rem; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;">
  <table style="border-spacing: 0px; font-size:1rem; margin:0; padding:0; table-layout:fixed; width:100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          a
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          b
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          c
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          d
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          e
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          f
        </th>
        <th style="background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; font-weight:bold; position:sticky; top:0; width:150px;">
          g
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#e8e8e8; height:1000px">1</td>
        <td style="height:1000px">2</td>
        <td style="background-color:#e8e8e8; height:1000px">3</td>
        <td style="height:1000px">4</td>
        <td style="background-color:#e8e8e8; height:1000px">5</td>
        <td style="height:1000px">6</td>
        <td style="background-color:#e8e8e8; height:1000px">7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The border at the bottom of the first tr goes up now when I scroll ... is there a way to see that one always?

Answer (score 0):

> **Gentle tip:** I found it a lot easier to work on your `<table>` once I had separated out the CSS from the HTML. Keeping **Presentation**
> *(CSS)* and **Structure** *(HTML)* - and **Behaviour** *(JS)* - separate is definitely a good practice.
>
> **Further Reading:** [Why is it (or was it) important to separate CSS from
> HTML?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271294/why-is-it-or-was-it-important-to-separate-css-from-html)

---

Four steps:

1. Remove the border from the `<table>` and add the border to the parent `<div>` instead
2. Add `border-spacing: 0` to the `<table>`
3. Add `border: 2px solid #fff` to all the `<th>` elements
4. Add `border: 2px solid #fff` ***and*** `border-top: 0px;` to all the `<td>` elements

---

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.container table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.container table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.container table td {
 height: 1000px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-top: 0px;
}

.container table td:nth-of-type(odd) {
background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table>

<thead>
<tr>
<th>a</th>
<th>b</th>
<th>c</th>
<th>d</th>
<th>e</th>
<th>f</th>
<th>g</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
</div>
```